# Relay board design issues with the relay driver

Tags: arduino, relay, shift-register

I have followed the [post](http://www.mikeburdis.com/wp/projects/16-channel-relay-multiplexer-shield-for-arduino-nano/) and tried to control multiple relays using Arduino. Instead of using the original relay, I used [NA-5W-K](https://www.fcl.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fcai/relays/na.pdf). However, the relay on my designed PCB doesn't work.

The original design used an Arduino Nano to send signals to multiple 74HC595 8-bit output register. And those 74HC595 are connected to the relay driver ULN2803 to drive each individual relays.

I have made little modification with the original design (refer to the Shift registers and relay drivers in that post). My OUT1_1 is one of the outputs of ULN2803.

I suppose the relay driver would drive my relays. I have checked that each of the 74HC595 output is working well. When I connect the 74HC595 output to the ULN2803 and drive the relays, it seems that the relay wouldn't drive. However, when I removed the ULN2803, and directly connect the output of each 74HC595 to my OUT1_1, the relays work. Do I actually need the relay driver and why it causes the failure of the system?

[image: Relay diagram design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ULN2803 has open collector outputs - it is a transistor with the emitter grounded and the collector connected to the output pin.  The ULN2803 can only pull its output to ground, or let the output float.

Since you have grounded one side of the relay coil, the ULN2803 cannot cause the relay to operate.

You need to connect the relay coil + terminal to the positive supply, and connect the relay coil - terminal to the ULN2803 output to allow the ULN2803 to control the relay.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and it works. Really appreciate it. For the flyback diode, is it correct to make the anode of the diode to the relay coil + terminal and the cathode of the diode to the ULN2803 output (which also connected to the coil-)?

Comment: @Dario: the ULN2803 has internal diodes connected anodes to each output and cathodes to pin 12. Connect pin 12 to the relay positive supply to use these internal diodes as flyback diodes.

Answer (score 1):

Page 1 of the [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74HC595.pdf), Features, says "Sinks or Sources 8mA at VCC = 4.5V".

Meanwhile, the relay datasheet, coil rating table says that the 5 V version coil resistance is 178 Ω. We can calculate the required current as \$ I = \frac V R = \frac 5 {178} = 28 \text {mA} \$. This is 350% of the rated output.

I recommend use of the ULN2803 but note that due to the Darlington transistor arrangement in the outputs that it can only pull down to about 1 V leaving only 4 V for the relay if running on a 5 V supply. See V<sub>CEsat</sub> on the [ULN2803 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/uln2803a.pdf), page 3.

I recommend you add details of the ULN version of your circuit into your question so we can check it. They're simple and reliable chips so it should be easy enough.